# Has the speed of light ever been measured in vacuum?

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light, measurements, vacuum, cosmic-microwave-background

According to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background the CMB (Cosmic Microwave Background) "is faint cosmic background radiation **filling all space**"

Also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum#Outer_space says "**no vacuum is truly perfect**, not even in interstellar space, where there are still a few hydrogen atoms per cubic meter"

And https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/vacuum/info: "This rather theoretical requirement is **never achieved in practice**, because even if space does not contain any atoms / electrons / nucleons, it does contain a lot of photons and neutrinos. But **we still call it a vacuum, as an approximation of the theoretical vacuum**."

Then on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light we have "**The speed of light in vacuum**, commonly denoted c, is a universal physical constant important in many areas of physics. **Its exact value is 299,792,458 metres per second** (approximately 300,000 km/s (186,000 mi/s)). It is exact because by international agreement a metre is defined as the length of the path travelled by light in vacuum during a time interval of 1/299792458 second"

Given that, at least according to Wikipedia, in practice vacuum does not exist, and it's filled with radiation, **is it actually possible to measure the speed of light in vacuum**? Also, has anyone even **observed light in vacuum**, ever?

If not, what types of vacuums has light been measured in? Are there any records about this?

Additionally, if true vacuum doesn't even seem to exist and it's filled with radiation (CMB), **can we really assume that light doesn't need a medium to propagate?** Wouldn't it effectively be propagating through whatever is filling up the space? Would we ever be able to tell the difference?

Comment: Are you suggesting that electromagnetic radiation (light) propagates through electromagnetic radiation (CMB microwaves)? Doesn’t that seem problematic?

Comment: Have you tried to estimate the effects?

Comment: I've removed a comment that should have been an answer, and replies to it. Please use comments to improve the question, and use answers to answer the question.

Comment: How would you measure an exact value?

Comment: @safesphere that's a very powerful question. Maybe even an unanswerable question.

Comment: @G.Smith if light is an electromagnetic radiation, it could be interpreted that either there's an "eletric wave" traveling through a "magnetic field", or vice versa, depending on the direction you want to assume or that you observe. It would also in a way be a nice fit with Newton's third law.

Comment: If you interpreted it that way, then it would be your personal theory, not mainstream physics. This site does not allow personal theories. If it did, it would be inundated with nonsense. In mainstream physics, light is an EM wave, and electric waves do not travel through magnetic fields or vice versa.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

There are many answers which point at different ways of understanding the question and convey different types of information about it. I am very thankful for everyone that has contributed to this discussion.

This answer is to condense the info contained in the other answers so far, which together I feel do answer the posted question.

Here's what I learned:

1) We have actually never observed light in "true vacuum", as "true vacuum" doesn't really exist (or it is ill-defined)

2) Given 1), we haven't really been able to measure the speed of light in vacuum. However, this doesn't seem to matter, as we have agreed to define the speed of light as a fixed quantity

3) There is no universally-accepted definition of vacuum, it means different things in different fields or contexts

4) Despite 1), 2), and 3), it doesn't really matter for the purposes of physics, because the models work anyway and the models are not reality, just useful mathematical tools to help us make predictions

5) There aren't really any absolute units of anything. Constants and units are abstract concepts defined through the mathematical models of physics and the values of the units are defined by agreement and governed by the SI. So for example, there is no problem with defining the speed of light as a function of the meter and at the same time defining the meter in terms of the speed of light

Comment: The speed of light is not “defined as a function of the meter”. It is a fundamental property of our universe and is not tied to a specific system of units. If there are intelligent aliens on some far away planet somewhere who have thought about physics, I assure you they understand very well what the notion of the speed of light means, and know its value in their own system of units, even if they never heard of a “meter”.

Comment: @GenlyAi I'm confused, are you saying the speed of light is not really a speed? In that case, what would it be instead? and how could it be used to then define the rest of the units? Or are you saying that speeds don't need to have units of distance/time?

Comment: Here is an example of a fundamental property that can be expressed without reference to any particular unit of length: the [Balmer series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_series) An intelligent species on another planet will at some point in its technological development discover that the multiple lines of the hydrogen spectrum are interconnected as described by the Balmer series. The Balmer series exists, independent of what units you happen to use to express the indidual lines of the hydrogen spectrum. The speed of light exists, independent of what unit you use to express it.

Comment: @NicoBrenner no, I’m not saying any of these things. The speed of light is definitely a speed, and speed measures distance per unit of time. None of this contradicts what I said earlier. I think you’re fixating on the idea that in the triple of units: time, distance, speed, it is time and distance that are the more fundamental ones, and speed is a derived concept. But that’s not true: in fact, each two of those three can be used to define the third. So, you can define a unit of distance by fixing a unit of time (a second) and a unit of speed (the universe conveniently provides that one).

Answer (score 22):

Science is full of ideals in its wordings.  This is one of them.

SI has *fixed* the speed of light in a vacuum to be 299,792,458 m/s.  If there was indeed light propagating through a perfect vacuum, that would be its speed ... because we define it to be.

For practical purposes, however, we need to be able to design experiments with which to measure distances using this definition.  We have done these sorts of experiment regularly in high vacuum, on par with or more extreme than the vacuum of interstellar space.  When we look at the effect matter has in slowing the speed of light, we find that the difference between its speed in a perfect vacuum and an achievable vacuum is smaller than the measurement error on our experimental devices.  Before we had fixed the speed of light to be a constant, we had [measured it](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SpeedOfLight/measure_c.html) to within 1 m/s.

How much of an effect does it have?  I'm having trouble finding sources to give a definitive answer, but based on the refractive index of hydrogen as a function of pressure, I would expect interstellar levels of hydrogen to slow light by a factor on the order of µm/s.  It's very difficult to measure physical things to 8 or 9 digits, and µm/s is 15 digits away from the speed of light, so our measurements in a high vacuum are as usable as if they were in a perfect vacuum.

If, at some point in the future, we discover that this approach is flawed, we will amend it, as has been done several times before—the most recent amendment being fixing the kilogram as a function of several fundamental constants.

Comment: So what is the meaning of the speed of light as being 299,792,458 m/s, if the m there (1 meter) is defined in terms of the speed of light? ("a metre is defined as the length of the path travelled by light in vacuum during a time interval of 1/299792458 second"). They both depend on each other, which makes both definitions either invalid, or basically whatever it is agreed on what they are, without consideration for actual reality.

Also, if we can't remove all EM radiation from where we measure light in, how can we know that light doesn't somehow depend on that radiation for propagation?

Comment: @NicoBrenner The meaning is to define the meter.  Once you have defined a second (which is defined based on the superfine transitions of Cesium), you can define the meter by using a beam of light and the fact that we defined its velocity.  As for the issue of the fact that we cannot remove all EM radiation, light exhibits superposition.  If you have two light waves which cross, you can figure out what happens by taking each light wave individually and then summing the two effects.  Each lightwave has the same effect as-if no other lightwave existed.

Comment: One might be more pedantic, and say that light travels at 299,792,458 m/s in any arbitrary EM radiation environment, but because light exhibits superposition, it's much easier to just say that it travels that fast in a perfect vacuum, and the superposition laws of light show that it will travel *exactly* the same speed in any EM environment.  Now this, itself, is a *bit* of a simplification.  At *really really really really* extreme brightness levels of light, we actually do see some quantum interactions within light waves.  But at the low end...

Comment: ..., such as anything below 2.4GW in air, we can say that two light beams simply do not interact with eachother in any meaningful way (there are a handful of lasers in the entire world powerful enough to exhibit this effect).  And the SI measurement takes that to its ultimate extreme -- a perfect vacuum.

Comment: Given all of that, the goal of the SI system defining the speed of light, defining a second, and other things like that, is to permit you to recreate precisely the same system of measurement as was used on past experiments (to within a reasonable level of error).

Comment: thank you for your insightful explanations. What I interpret from them then is that units are basically a tool based on agreements, that allow us to compare experimental results. However, none of these units are in any way "absolute", rather they are all relative to whatever the latest agreement of the units are.

Comment: @NicoBrenner Yes, for as many units as we have been able to manage.  However, just one year ago, we could say that the kilogram was an absolute measure.  There was a lump of Platinum-Irridium alloy sitting in a French vault from which the kilogram was defined.  There has been a great interest as of late to get away from such approaches, and to instead fix our unit systems to what appear to be constants of our universe.

Comment: For most students, it's effective to think of units as absolute concrete things.  There *is* a kilogram, there *is* a meter, and you're going to like it!  Its much easier to think that way.  However, for some people (myself included), it is much easier to make sense of units by realizing that they are more of a relative method of conveying information between people, and nothing more than that.  That way of thinking is much harder to think through, but if your brain is wired that way, there's nothing wrong with thinking that way!

Comment: But a kg, even in physical form, varies over time, so anything defined relative to that would also vary over time. And then "the constants of our universe" are actually "the constants we have defined through our mathematical models and which we have agreed to have certain values that we might change over time".

You answered my comment before I even finished writing it :)

Comment: @NicoBrenner Yes, or perhaps to be kinder, i'd say they are values which we have found absolutely no reason to believe are not constant.  Science has a long track record of finding ways to turn constants into variables, given enough time and money to experiment with, but we'll treat them as constants while we can.  Exploring that venue starts to get into the philosophy of science, which you might find very rewarding.

Comment: @NicoBrenner That's exactly why the kilogram prototype was made out of that Platinum-Irridium alloy stored under very carefully maintained environment; we can get good numbers about the variation of the kilogram prototype, and it was accurate enough for any practical macroscopic purpose. The new definitions simply allow us to have a real standardised measure even for extremely small and extremely large objects. You might want to pick up some book about the history of measurement, because it's one of the really big problems in science and engineering. We just keep getting better at it :)

Answer (score 12):

The “few atoms of hydrogen per cubic meter” is a vacuum for visible light. The adjective “perfect” is both unnecessary and irrelevant in describing light propagating through a vacuum.

The wavelength of visible light is around 500 nm. So roughly $8 \ 10^{18}$ wavelengths fit in a cubic meter. A few hydrogen atoms are utterly irrelevant. Their presence cannot explain the wave behavior of light and from the perspective of such a phenomena the region is vacuum.

Since neutrinos don’t interact with light, their presence is also unimportant, regardless of their quantity. And photons are the same thing as light so it hardly makes sense to complain about the presence of photons when discussing the presence of light.

Comment: In an answer below @GenlyAi says "the truth is we don’t really know what light is and how or why it propagates". So is the wavelength of light an actual physical observable thing, or is it an interpretation of the way the light behaves and used in physical models because it correlates nicely with experimental evidence? Also, given that "a metre is defined as the length of the path travelled by light in vacuum during a time interval of 1/299792458 second" there's a circular definition, how can you know what a nm actually is?

Comment: Shouldn’t you ask GlenlyAi about that statement? I completely disagree with it and certainly will not try to justify it. There is no known EM phenomenon that is not included in our current model of EM. Also, there is no circularity involved there. Not sure why you think there is.

Comment: about the circular definition: a meter is defined as a function of the speed of light (the length of the path travelled by light in vacuum during a time interval of 1/299792458 second), but the speed of light is defined in terms of meters. So c depends on the definition of what a meter is, but a meter is defined in terms of c. How is that not a circular definition? There's no "real" definition of anything there, just an arbitrary/agreed-upon proportion between two concepts.

Comment: The meter depends on the speed of light. The speed of light does not depend on the meter. There is no circularity whatsoever.

Comment: The speed of light is defined in meters per second, and the meter is defined in terms of the speed of light. Not sure why you think there's no circular dependency there. Maybe you are ignoring the units of speed (?).

Comment: @NicoBrenner No, the speed of light is often *expressed* in meters per second. It doesn't depend on the *definition* of a meter in the slightest (it used to, but back then, the *meter* wasn't defined in terms of the light speed, so again, there was no circular dependency). You're mixing two different definitions of the speed of light and the meter. Pick one, and your confusion will disappear.

Comment: @NicoBrenner As per modern definitions, the speed of light in a vacuum is a fixed number in the units of `m/s`. If we measured the speed of light in a vacuum to be different than that number, the result would be a different length for the meter. The meter depends on the speed of light in a vacuum, but not vice versa. But in the end, even that wouldn't really happen, because the speed of light is not really the speed of light in a vacuum anyway - it has a much more general meaning, and light happens to be one of the things that propagates at the so-called speed of light.

Comment: @NicoBrenner if the speed of light depends on the definition of the meter then how did light propagate in the billions of years prior to the definition of the meter? Light propagated just fine prior to the BIPM using it to define the length of a meter. Furthermore, not only is your objection obviously wrong, it is completely irrelevant to my answer. In dimensionless terms there is on the order of 10^18 wavelengths of visible light in the volume occupied by a single hydrogen atom. The use of the meter in the answer is because it was used in the question, but any units could be used.

Comment: Clearly there's a problem in the meaning of the physical models and the language used to talk about them. They are presented and written about as if they are reality, even if in reality they are just models to represent reality. In this case, you are saying that 1) the speed of light is a human definition, 2) the speed of light is a fundamental thing of nature that doesn't require human definition. Then both are used conveniently when it fits the description.

Comment: Don’t say “you are saying that” when I did not say it. Either quote me exactly or don’t attribute a statement to me.

Comment: @Dale may I ask what exactly about my statement you disagree with? I agree with what you said that “there is no known EM phenomenon that is not included in our current model of EM”, and that isn’t at all inconsistent with what I said that we don’t really understand how light propagates. Having a model that enables you to make successful predictions is one thing, understanding what is “really” going on (if that is even a meaningful question - it’s not obvious that it is) is yet another, quite separate, level of understanding.

Comment: @GenlyAi I disagree that there exists another separate level of understanding. If you have a model that predicts every possible observable aspect of a phenomenon then your model already captures everything that there is to know about it and there is nothing else “really” going on. If you came up with some new aspect then it would be entirely unobservable (by the original premise that the model captures everything observable) and therefore the new aspect would not merit the designation of “real”. So we do know what light is and how it propagates.

Comment: @Dale got it, thanks. I agree that’s a reasonable way to look at things, though my own opinion differs.

Comment: I feel the same, which is why I didn’t downvote your answer nor did I intend to comment on it at all. And I was therefore more than a little irritated at the OP when he pushed the issue on me anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to address your confusion about whether the definitions are circular...
I think the root of your confusion may be in understanding what this means from the Wikipedia article you quoted:

> Its exact value is 299,792,458 metres per second

You bolded the above sentence, but it is not really the important one. The important one was later in your quote:

> a metre is defined as the length of the path travelled by light in vacuum during a time interval of 1/299792458 second

I think you also may be confused about the difference between values and the physical quantities they represent.

So to determine what a meter is based on the above definition, you first need to *measure* the speed of light. Imagine you are able to make an experiment that measures how far light goes in 1 second. Perhaps it draws pencil marks on two walls very far apart. Say you run the experiment 10 times and look at the different results. The outputs from the different runs of the are *not* values like [299792458.1 m, 299792457.7 m, 299792458.3 m, ...]. Instead, the outputs are *all* called "299792458 m". Of course they do have measurement error, but the error is in the actual physical measurement (the locations of the pencil marks).

If someone wants to use this experiment to, say, manufacture a very accurate meter stick (maybe a "light-second stick" in this case), they would need to actually use their meter stick to measure the distance between the pencil marks on the wall, and use that to know whether their meter stick is too large or two small and adjust their manufacturing process based on that.

Does this give you any insight, or am I off base here about your confusion?

Comment: Thank you Justin, I really appreciate your answer and explanation. What you are saying makes sense. However, I am not really confused. To define the concept of speed, you are using the concepts of time and distance. Which is fine if you want them to be purely conceptual, but the moment you try to pin them down to something "real", then everything becomes relative to whatever you arbitrarily choose as the base to measure everything else.

Comment: To illustrate using your example, how would you time that 1 second in your experiment to determine the speed of light relative to the walls? Lets say you use some sort of watch. Now, how is that watch's time defined? Can you make the definition of the watch's time independent from other physical measures/units?

Comment: @NicoBrenner - You don't actually need to define the concept of speed at all to carry out the imaginary experiment I proposed. You just need to measure how far light goes during 1 second. Distance is still real without meters.

Comment: The second is defined as ""the duration of 9,192,631,770 periods of the radiation corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the caesium-133 atom" (at a temperature of 0 K)", per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second). Some care was taken that this definition does not depend on meters, etc. Fundamentally, it is just a count.

Comment: That definition of second requires for a time duration (1 second) to have been measured (or arbitrarily chosen) before relating it to the "9,192,631,770 periods of the radiation...". It also requires somehow measuring (counting) the radiation periods, how is that done?

Comment: No, the definition of a second does not require a second to have been measured. The definition of a second tell you what you need to measure to determine what a second is. For more about how the counting is done, read [Atomic Clock (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_clock).

Comment: The strange looking value of 9,192,631,770 was chosen so that the new definition of a second matches closely to previous definitions of the second (e.g., measurement of some fraction of the time it takes the Earth to orbit the sun). But that's really just a historical tidbit now -- you can just consider 9,192,631,770 to be an arbitrary number.

Comment: The process/history of measurement is important, because it shows how all measurements essentially depend on previous measurements and their derived definitions. For example, to construct an Atomic Clock, a lot of units and measurements, based on previous ones, were used. So if the current definition of a second depends on measuring something with an Atomic Clock, then that definition cannot be "untangled" or severed from the measurements, units and assumptions that were used to build that Atomic Clock.

Comment: If you are going to include both current *and previous* definitions, they will be not only circular, but inconsistent. You need to choose whether you want to have a human/historical view of units or whether you want to have a self-consistent/scientific view of them. You can't really do both at the same time. The history of measurement may be important and good to know, but you can't make sense out of the new SI definitions unless you understand them as full redefinitions.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are going to include historical and current definitions of units, you are not really talking about the same units and you could denote it that way somehow. E.g., x = 1 meterA = 1.01 meterB.

Comment: Thank you @Justin for the clarification. For me it is important to understand where things are coming from to interpret their meaning. What you are saying reaffirms that current units and measurement are arbitrary agreements in physics to enable a more precise correlation and understanding across experiments, and they are not "real" physical properties.

Comment: Yes, that's a pretty good way of saying it. The units are a means of communication about the physical properties, but they are definitely not as real as the properties themselves.

Answer (score 1):

> the CMB (Cosmic Microwave Background) "is faint cosmic background radiation **filling all space**" [...]
>
> Given that, at least according to Wikipedia, in practice vacuum does not exist, and it's filled with radiation, [...]

You seem to be assuming that a vacuum in which electromagnetic radiation (such as the CMB) is present is not a “true” vacuum. But if you define the vacuum in such a way, then we could *never* measure the speed of light in a vacuum, because as soon as you inject light into the vacuum it stops being a perfect vacuum. See the problem here? Your notion of what a vacuum is is a much too purist and restrictive one.

> Additionally, if true vacuum doesn't even seem to exist and it's filled with radiation (CMB), **can we really assume that light doesn't need a medium to propagate?**

I think what you mean is that light can propagate in a vacuum (that is, that light doesn’t need *matter* to propagate), not that light doesn’t need a medium to propagate. As for a “medium”, the truth is we don’t really know what light is and how or why it propagates, so the statement about a medium belongs to the realms of philosophy or metaphysics, not physics. We do have excellent *mathematical descriptions* of light, the vacuum, and other physical phenomena. Our mathematical models say light propagates in a vacuum, and all existing experimental evidence confirms this to an overwhelming degree of certainty. That’s really all that physics has to say about this issue of propagation.

Comment: You are right that a vacuum with light in it wouldn't be a true vacuum. However my point was, what happens when light is demonstrably the only thing in a vacuum? It seems like we've never seen that.

Comment: @Nico I didn’t say that a vacuum with light in it wouldn’t be a true vacuum. It was you who said it, and I pointed out that such a definition makes your question unanswerable (Dale expressed a similar sentiment in the last sentence of his answer). As for whether it is actually a correct statement, I think that depends on the context, since vacuum is typically taken to mean either “space devoid of matter” (which allows the presence of photons) or “the lowest energy state of a quantum field” (which doesn’t). In the context of measuring the speed of light, I’m pretty sure CMB is irrelevant.

Comment: @NicoBrenner the part of your question that did make sense to me is the one questioning whether the presence of hydrogen atoms in interstellar space, rather than CMB, affects our measurement of the speed of light. Cort Ammon answered that nicely.